# pycrypto develoment server error "from Crypto.Cipher import blockalgo"

Tags: google-app-engine, encryption, cryptography, pycrypto

I have installed pycrypto version 2.6 , and i am getting this error

```
from Crypto.Cipher import blockalgo
ImportError: cannot import name blockalgo
```

I have read many post but i am unable to solve this problem

Comment: Posiible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252436/pycrypto-in-google-app-engine-development-server-importerror-cannot-import-nam

Comment: Also tried that one , but still not working

Comment: Does this happen on the development server? How does your development environment look like. Eclipse / Pydev?

Comment: I you use Eclipse with Pydev: Have you added the lib to your Python interpreter path. And if that is not enough, you can try a forced build-in.

Comment: Also tried this one , still not working

Comment: And you have installed 1.7.2? Have you tried creating an new project using 1.7.2. Sometimes the libs you can select have changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not able to import anything from Crypto.Cipher at all, it might be due to folders,  crypto and respective egg info, under site-packages are created with lower-case 'c'

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/crypto
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/crypto-1.0.0-py2.7.egg-info
```

Imports were successful when same case was used while importing

```
from crypto.Cipher import AES
```

or renaming the folders

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Crypto-1.0.0-py2.7.egg-info
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Crypto
```

I went with the later, to have consistency with others.

I use Eclipse and was able to overcome this problem using one of the above solutions.
Sometimes we overlook these kind of details easily. Its a long shot, hope this helps!